# Swagger PHP shared responses

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-php

The problem is the following:
I have an API where of course every endpoint has a specific type of response in case of successful call. But all the endpoints share the same kind of response when something wrong happened.
For example when the request contained invalid parameters every endpoint returns a 400 status code with a specific content which describes the issue.
And the same for authentication or authorization issues.
I tried to put the shared responses to the entry point of the application and they are in the generated swagger.json but they are not related to the endpoints.
I'd like to all the endpoints contain all the shared responses and their specific response as well.
I can do it by simply parsing the json, and adding the responses by a script but I though there must be a better way to do this.

Here is an example action doc just in case:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Post(
 *     path="/integration/create",
 *     description="Creates the given integration",
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="body",
 *         in="body",
 *         required=true,
 *         @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/IntegrationCreateRequest"),
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response="204",
 *         description="Successful creation",
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response="400",
 *         description="Invalid request parameters",
 *         @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/InvalidRequestResponse"),
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response="401",
 *         description="Unauthenticated request",
 *     )
 * )
 */
```

The last two responses can be declared to all the endpoints what I want to avoid of course